# Can FCPX work with vector graphics?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I've tried to import **.eps** and **.ai** files unsuccessfully. Are there any vector formats supported by FCPX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Or at least not yet. According to this post:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2323932

**EDIT:**
Here's the [offical supported media formats for FCPX](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12754?locale=en_ZA) from the Apple support site. It shows that those formats are not supported.

Comment: Note that the linked discussion is about FCP7, not FCPX, which this question was about.

Comment: @user1118321 Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the question with some official documentation from Apple.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a workaround I've discovered that seems to work ok. It's not elegant, but it gives you vector support within FCPX, which can be handy in a number of situations. It does require Apple Motion, however.

1. Convert your vector file into a PDF using Preview.
2. Create a Final Cut Generator in Apple Motion
3. Import PDF
4. Click the PDF in the "Media" pane (next to the Viewer), then in the inspector, un-click "Fixed Resolution" in the "Media" tab.
5. Drag the file into your composition.
6. Save As...

This will create a generator in FCPX, which is a little more permanent than making a simple file. But if you're doing work for a client and want a persistent vector version of their logo or something, this can be very helpful.

Comment: Dan.. You just saved me from buying AI... I think Apple Motion converts to .PDF itself when I import the .AI file.. so that saves a step. I could also choose whether or not to use the background, which was exactly what I needed. I then needed to convert the color from black to white.. which was easily done by pulling up the exposure completely.

Comment: Great workaround, unfortunately I wasn't looking for something that permanent. I just wanted to be able to quickly import and use vector files, similar to how PNGs are used.

Answer (score -1):

I have downloaded and installed Affinity for a one time price.  Affinity runs only on a Mac, will directly import layered AI and PDF files.  Then you can render out PNG and JPGs in any resolution you require for your project.  It is quick and convenient once you get past the learning curve.  Good luck.